# Вопрос по счётчику YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Есть одна задачка, и мне пока даже непонятно, куда копать...

Суть вот в чем: вывожу на сайте видео с YouTube, и чего-то захотел показать количество просмотров рядом.

Возник вопрос: возможно ли каким-нибудь образом получить это количество с YouTube? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/ru/api-resources.html тут есть методы для получения видео, там же есть и ваш счетчик просмотров. (В JSONe поле order, в одном из методов, возвращает viewCount.)